# c++ vector : initializing with cin in a loop

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I'm new to programming and i have problem with some items
i would appreciate any help
first i started initializing the vector as followed but i couldn't end the loop with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector <double> temps;
    double temp;
    cout << "Enter a sequence of tempreatures : " << "\n" ;
    while (cin >> temp){
        temps.push_back(temp);
        }
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i< temps.size(); ++i)
        sum += temps[i];
    cout << "Mean temprature : " << sum / temps.size() << "\n";
    sort(temps.begin(), temps.end());
    cout << "Median temprature : " << temps[temps.size() / 2];
```

then i changed the while into this format :

```
cout << "ENter a sequence of tempreatures ending in 1500 : " << "\n" ;
    while (cin >> temp){
        if (temp == 1500)
            break;
        temps.push_back(temp);
        }
```

now i have this error
"vector subscript out of range"
apparently break does not work properly here
what should i do?

Comment: What is `</i>` at the end of your median temperature output line? What are you trying to do in your `while` loop and why did you add a `break` condition? Where does your error occur in the code? Please format your code properly (i.e. fix syntax, spelling, spacing, etc.), clearly post what you are trying to do and why, and post concise error messages you get from your console.

Comment: Well, you're having an infinite loop as far as I can see. Add a condition that breaks the loop into `while`

Comment: i corrected it that </i> thing was sth was added while i was trying to post my question here. but im telling you it doesnt stop the while it never goes inside my for loop

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is in the check condition of for loop.

```
 for (int i = 0; i, temps.size(); ++i)
    sum += temps[i];
```

It should be

```
 for (int i = 0; i < temps.size(); ++i)
```

`i, temps.size()` will evaluate and then ignore the part before `,` and are left with `temps.size()` as check condition which will always be greater than `0` if you `push_back` at least one element and your loop will never end.You might want to read how `,(comma)` works.

Comment: thank you , i corrected my typing mistake but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

If you switch to `std::getline` into a string instead of `std::cin` into a double, you can check whether the input is empty:

```
std::string input;
std::getline(std::cin, input);
while (!input.empty()){
    temps.push_back(atof(input.c_str()));
    std::getline(std::cin, input);
}
```

If you also fix the `for`-loop as mentioned by Gaurav Sehgal, it works fine (Enter all numbers then hit enter without any input).

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows then you have to do 
 `CTRL + Z`

If you are on Unix based(Linux/Mac) then you have to do 
  `CTRL + D`

This will give the end of file signal and you will be able to break the loop

Comment: i tried that to it didnt work either cause its c++ console and apparently in console EOF doesnt work

Comment: are you doing this on an IDE or compiling from the terminal?
Try to compile using terminal and check once

Comment: i dont know what was the problem but when i rewrite the code it worked , thank u so much for your time and attention